# Salesforce Report Builder: Sorting by Grouped Total

Tags: salesforce

I have a pretty basic scenario: contacts have orders and orders have order line items.  An order has a forumla field on it to calculate the entire cost of the order and that is working fine.  I'm trying to create a report that shows each customer name and the summed dollar amounts of all orders for that customer.  So I drag the customer name onto the fields area and then add the order total field.  I group by the customer full name and then I set the group by on the order total column to sum and this works fine...but then I can't sort by that column.  I want to sort by total dollar amount so I can quickly see who is a high buying customer.  Is there a way to order a report by a summed field or will I just have to export to Excel and manipulate the data there?

Thanks
Josh

Comment: Since this isn't a code question (though it is Salesforce dev) you might get closed down here. Please join my proposal for a Salesforce Stack Exchange site to help people with these kinds of problems!

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37589/salesforce

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping since I was developing reports that this would be okay for SO, but a dedicated SO community would definitely be the right place for it.

Comment: Yeah, it's a fine line. For me it is part of force.com development, but it's not code so I understand where people come from. Apologies for not answering, but reports is one of my weakest areas - pretty sure you can do this through the reporting engine though!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that this is possible. I've recreated your scenario with the standard Opportunity object and the Amount field. I have grouped on both Opportunity Name and Amount. Clicking on the down arrow button on the group gives a menu that allows you to change the sort order of the group as shown in this image.

[image: Here is an image of my report fields]

I think the fields in your report should behave in the same way.